# Calculate value if same customer

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

I have the following code to count days:

*count_days*:

```
DATEDIFF('day',LOOKUP(ATTR([visit_day]),-1),ATTR([visit_day])
```

and the outcome is the following:

```
customer_id | visit_day | count_days
customer 1  | 1/1/2016  | 
customer 2  | 1/3/2016  | 2
customer 2  | 1/15/2016 | 12
customer 3  | 2/1/2016  | 16
customer 3  | 2/5/2016  | 4
```

I'm trying to write another function that fires the previous function only by customer, so the first day of one customer is not subtracted by the last day of the previous customer. The outcome should look like this:

```
customer_id | visit_day | count_days
customer 1  | 1/1/2016  | 
customer 2  | 1/3/2016  |
customer 2  | 1/15/2016 | 12 
customer 3  | 2/1/2016  | 
customer 3  | 2/5/2016  | 4
```

I have tried this code so far:

```
IF ATTR([customer_id]) != ATTR([customer_id])
THEN
   NULL
ELSE
   [count_days]
END
```

Any thoughts about this code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You can alter your calculated field like so:

```
IF LOOKUP(ATTR([Customer Id]),-1) = ATTR([Customer Id]) THEN 
   DATEDIFF("day",LOOKUP(ATTR([Visit Day]),-1),ATTR([Visit Day]))
END
```

It will render this result:

[image]

Comment: I almost got it. I'm new to Tableau though, but getting there. Thank you very much for your solution.